# Is it possible to have 2 context menus in same activity?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have an activity with `TextView` and an image icon. I already created context menu for the image icon by overriding [`onCreateContextMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu%28android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo%29).

However, I would like also to have another context menu for the `TextView`. However, I notice I'm already utilizing `onCreateContextMenu()`:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.option1));  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.option2));  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.options3));  
}
```

Hence, is there away to add another context menu for the `TextView`?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641259/how-can-i-create-multiple-context-menus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the passed View object in **onCreateContextMenu** to determine the owner of the menu and populate a menu accordingly.

Your code should look something like this :

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.imageIconId:
             menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.option1));  
             menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.option2));   
             menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.options3));  
           break;
          case R.id.textViewid:
            // do whatever you want with the menu object.
           break;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameters passed to you by that method will help you branch to different things.

Here is an example:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        if( v.equals(yourImgView) ){
            menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.option1));  
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.option2));  
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, getString(R.string.options3));  
        }else if ( v.equals(yourTxtView) ) {
            //Do your textView things.
        }

    }
```